# Aptana odd block coloring

Tags: netbeans, ide, aptana

I am having an issue with Aptana that hopefully someone else has experience and solved. My code between tags is being highlighted. This is not just an Aptana problem I have tried it in Netbeans as well.

Dont have enough rep to post images here so sorry for the links.

[This picture is the default theme for Aptana.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7TU5.png)

[And this is the city lights for Netbeans.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvAMo.png)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Inside the themes/fonts and color there is an option that deals with javascript embedded in html. That was where the strange color came from. I switched it to inheritance and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed through the 'Themes' preferences.
Locate the 'Embedded Source' item (for the 'text source' scope). In the default Aptana Studio dark theme, you'll need to match it to the background color, which is an RGB value of 20, 20, 20.

Cheers